# Storing pyplot object in variable

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, terminal

Please refer to the following code.

```
>>> p = plt.plot(year, rank)
>>> p.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'show'
>>> plt.plot(year, rank)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f3b56443890>]
>>> plt.show()
```

When I try to store `plt` in a variable `p`, it showing the `AttributeError:`
But when directly use `plt.show()`, it's working. I am not able to understand the difference.
I am using `python 2.7` in `Ubuntu 16.4`, and running the program from `terminal`.

Comment: that's not plt you're storing, just the return value of `plt.plot` which returns a `Line2D` object. plt is matplotlib.pyplot "stored"

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot(x,y)` returns a list of `Line2D` objects. You store this list in a variable `p`. As the error tells you, `'list' object has no attribute 'show'`. This can be taken literally, because `show()` is a function in the `matplotlib.pyplot` module and any normal python `list` does not even know about the existence of matplotlib.

You may of course still store the list in a variable, but in order to show the plot you need to use `plt.show()` independent of where you stored the return of any plotting commands

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p = plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.show()` is executing only once. If I call it again, it's not showing. I don't know the reason.